# How to enable zoom in images set to 100% width in CSS?

Tags: css, image

How to enable zoom in images even though they are set to 100% width in CSS?

This question might sound contradictionary -- if you set something to 100% width

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.66em;
```

you want it like that, don't you?

Well ... Figure this: There's a gallery of images which you want to be 100% wide. The user zooms, and this will only zoom the text. The images will continue to be 100% at whatever zoom level.

What I would like is this behaviour:

The images are 100% wide at neutral zoom level, but when the user zooms the page, the images are zoomed as well, though: The images are resized to always be 100% of the window, even when user resizes browser (if in normal zoom).

**Is there a CSS only solution to this?**

**A possible solution using javascript** would be setting the image width to the px of browser window in javascript instead. Zoom will work for the images as expected. When the user resizes browser javascript has to change the width of the images again.

Answer (score 2):

**The zoom behavior is browser dependent and even configurable**, depending on the browser your visitors use, the behavior is either what you describe or what you want already!

The only way control the behavior is to implement zooming yourself. Javascript is one way but keep in mind that the *browser zoom* is never under your control. It is there for accessibility reasons. Your own zoom would allow users to zoom in another way on whichever elements you decide make your script work with.

Comment: Don't yet have the rep to vote up, but appreciate your answer a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this can't be done without JavaScript, due to the feature that you require is a zoom on the PX that they are hovering over... So yes you could get it too zoom in but the image would not change when they move the cursor across the image as you would expect. You should opt to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or any other JavaScript library such as [Mootools](http://mootools.net/).

Doing a simple search on [Google for something like jQuery Zoom](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery%20zoom) - you will be overwhelmed with the amount of plugins premade to make this task easy for you.

Here is two that I found that meet your requirements:

- [Jacklmoore jQuery Zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)
- jQZoom - [Example 4](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo4)
- Jquery Image Zoom Plugin - [Inner Zoom Example](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#inner-zoom)

Comment: Don't yet have the rep to vote up, but appreciate your answer a lot! Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all, bare in mind that without reputation you can make a question accepted by clicking the accept. I'm not suggesting you click accept on mine but at a later date if/when more people reply ensure you return and mark accept if you used their method. That way we can focus on unanswered questions ;)

Comment: Sure, I'll wait a while and choose what's most appropriate for the question, thanks for telling!

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue.

First thing to point is that zoom still works on mobile devices. For other devices you can set min-width:100% instead of width. This will let you zoom in but not out.

Another solution is to set width in px depending on screen size using media queries like:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1440px)
@media only screen and (max-device-width:960px)
@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px)
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 550px)
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px)
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px)
```

Thank you!